# I can't solve higher Pandoc version required error

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I keep getting this error when I try to `render` and `Rmd` file

```
Erreur : pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

but when I type `pandoc_version()` in console I get

> rmarkdown::pandoc_available()

[1] TRUE

> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()

[1] ‘2.7.2’

Comment: Are you calling `render()` in the same R session as the code you're showing?

Comment: thank you for responding
yes it's the same session
and, I don't know if this changes anything but my rmd output is shiny doc and i am running the render script through php and I get the pandoc error

Comment: when I use rmarkdown::run it just opens an empty web page